# How can I get a list like this [30,31,32,33,34,35] when i give "in between 30 and 35" to a python function

Tags: python, regex

As I am not good in regular expression, please help me to get the define the method.
I have a method which takes string as argument and returns a list

```
 1. get_values("IN BETWEEN 30 AND 35")  => [30,31,32,33,34,35]
 2. get_values("(in between 35 and 40) and (in [56,57,58])") => [35,36,37,38,39,40,56,57,58]
 3. get_values("(in between 30 and 35) and (IN BETWEEN 40 AND 45)") =>[30,31,32,33,34,35,40,41,42,43,44,45]
```

These and their combinations are the possible cases

Comment: Did you see `range()` yet?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate the list, or how to parse the string? Will the string always start with "in between"?

Comment: Which bit(s) can you do? Do you know how to create a function that takes an argument? How to get `'30'` and `'35'` from the string? How to make those digit strings into integers? How to create the output list from those integers? How to return it? It would be helpful if you updated your question with the code you have so far and exactly what is wrong with it.

Comment: function takes only one argumemt shich is a string. it will be in the format "in between A and B"  or "in LIST and in between A and B" or any combination of these where A and B are numbers and LIST is a list of numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a potential solution, but this should really be handled by properly parsing the SQL syntax using some kind of parser:

```
import re
def get_values(sql):
    sql = sql.upper()
    between_regex = '(\d+)\s+AND\s+(\d+)'
    ranges = [range(int(a), int(b)) for a, b in re.findall(between_regex, sql)]

    in_regex = '\[(.*)]'
    ranges += [[int(y) for y in x.split(',')] for  x in re.findall(in_regex, sql)]
    return [x for r in ranges for x in r]

print get_values("IN BETWEEN 30 AND 35")
print get_values("(in between 35 and 40) and (in [56,57,58])")
print get_values("(in between 30 and 35) and (IN BETWEEN 40 AND 45)")

#[30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
#[35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 56, 57, 58]
#[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to search for the pattern in your string, where your lower and upper limits are the first and the second regex groups.
After that you just return the range. If you want to include the upper limit also, add `1` to `upper`.

```
import re

def get_values(myString):
    res = []
    m = re.search('in between\s+(\d+)\s+and\s+(\d+)', myString, re.IGNORECASE)
    p = re.search('in \[([\d, ]*)\]', myString, re.IGNORECASE)

    if m != None:
        lower = int(m.group(1))
        upper = int(m.group(2)) # add 1 here to include upper limit
        res.extend(range(lower,upper))

    if p != None:
        res.extend([int(x) for x in p.group(1).split(',')])

    # using set here to kill duplicates, you can remove
    # it if you want to preserve them
    res = list(set(res)) if res != None else []
    return res
```

The example of usage:

```
print get_values("in between 10 and 20 and in [1, 2,3]")
```

returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: You might want to add `re.IGNORECASE`

Answer (score 0):

Try this aproach:

```
>>> s = 'in between 30 and 35'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\\d')
>>> re.findall('\\d+', s)
['30', '35']

>>> p = re.findall('\\d+', s)
>>> range(p[0], p[1], 1)
>>> range(int(p[0]), int(p[1]), 1)
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
>>>
```

and so on...

ask me if you need more comments